# Reverse time/direction geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, mathematics, timeline

I have instances traveling along a curve based on the factor of 0 to 1 in a circle. I would like to click the switch and have the instance start traveling backwards from it's current position on the curve.

Currently it travels backwards with the switch, but makes a large jump to the new value.

How do I set this up so that the current value is the one it begins subtracting from once I turn on the switch node?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've found another solution that works for the functionality I was trying to create.

By using a "wrap" node I am able to keyframe a loop that moves forward, then by switching the offset to a negative value causes it to start moving in the opposite direction.

[image]